# xcode: Why can't I copy a file into a group in xcode?

Tags: xcode

I renamed my root project folder and opened it up in xcode.

about 20+ files shows up in red (indicates missing). I then delete the "red" files and tried to re-add them back.  but I get a copy error. "xcode cannot copy blah blah..."

1) How can I resolve this?
2) Is there a "Locate" feature that I dont know about?

---- RESOLVED ---

I didnt know that if there is a file with the same in physically in the project folder then xcode will not copy it to the project folder.

All i had to do is delete it from the project and then delete it from the file system. Or if the file you want is already in the project folder then you can re-add it back by not choosing the copy to folder option and also choose "relative to path" so next time you wont have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) Is there a "Locate" feature that I dont know about?

"Get Info" on any file or group, first tab, there is a button at the very right where you can choose a new path. Works even for multiple selection (if they are in the same directory).